# All Drupal function undefined in module page

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I had created my own module in D7. I created a new php page, callback.php, and access in my browser with url: ww.xxx.com/sites/all/modules/custom/seaqueen_module/pages/callback.php

When it calls any drupal function, such as drupal_set_message(), it shows error:
Fatal error: Call to undefined function drupal_set_message()

The same happens to other function such as  db_select(), db_insert(), db_update() , etc.

This error only occurs in the page callback.php, while other pages in this module works perfectly.

In my module .info file, I had inserted row below:

```
files[] = pages/callback.php
```

Cache is cleared and same error occurs. Is there anything I missed out and cause this error?

Comment: If you access your php file directly, drupal has not bootstrapped so none of the functions are defined. You should be using hook_menu to define a path.

Comment: You only need to include files[] in your .info for files which contain classes AFAIK